# Example Batch File To Start A Spot Instance Of Certain EC2 AMI?

Tags: windows, virtualization, amazon-ec2, batch-file

I want to start a certain EC2 AMI at the click of a button, well two buttons actually. Just to speed up testing / launch-time.

How would you call the EC2 API tools for windows via a batch file to start a **spot instance** of an AMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [ec2-request-spot-instances](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2009-11-30/CommandLineReference/index.html?ApiReference-cmd-RequestSpotInstances.html) command.  Remember that a spot instance won't start until the maximum price that you specify exceeds the current Spot Price, but you could use the [ec2-describe-spot-price-history](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2009-11-30/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeSpotPriceHistory.html) command to periodically check the spot price.